# What do this code doing?

Tags: java, collections

I have been reading "Thinking in Java" Bruce Eckel and I cannot understand what do this code doing:

```
  static Map<String,String> select(final int size) {
    return new FlyweightMap() {
      public Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> entrySet() {
        return new EntrySet(size);
      }
    };
  }
```

Full listing of programm:

```
package net.mindview.util;
import java.util.*;
import static net.mindview.util.Print.*;

public class Countries {
  public static final String[][] DATA = {
    // this is a big array "Country-Capital"
    {"ALGERIA","Algiers"}, {"ANGOLA","Luanda"},
    {"URUGUAY","Montevideo"}, {"VENEZUELA","Caracas"},
    // ...
  };
  // Use AbstractMap by implementing entrySet()
  private static class FlyweightMap
  extends AbstractMap<String,String> {
    private static class Entry
    implements Map.Entry<String,String> {
      int index;
      Entry(int index) { this.index = index; }
      public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return DATA[index][0].equals(o);
      }
      public String getKey() { return DATA[index][0]; }
      public String getValue() { return DATA[index][1]; }
      public String setValue(String value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
      }
      public int hashCode() {
        return DATA[index][0].hashCode();
      }
    }
    // Use AbstractSet by implementing size() & iterator()
    static class EntrySet
    extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<String,String>> {
      private int size;
      EntrySet(int size) {
        if(size < 0)
          this.size = 0;
        // Can't be any bigger than the array:
        else if(size > DATA.length)
          this.size = DATA.length;
        else
          this.size = size;
      }
      public int size() { return size; }
      private class Iter
      implements Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> {
        // Only one Entry object per Iterator:
        private Entry entry = new Entry(-1);
        public boolean hasNext() {
          return entry.index < size - 1;
        }
        public Map.Entry<String,String> next() {
          entry.index++;
          return entry;
        }
        public void remove() {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
      }
      public
      Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> iterator() {
        return new Iter();
      }
    }
    private static Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> entries =
      new EntrySet(DATA.length);
    public Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> entrySet() {
      return entries;
    }
  }
  // Create a partial map of 'size' countries:
  static Map<String,String> select(final int size) {
    return new FlyweightMap() {
      public Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> entrySet() {
        return new EntrySet(size);
      }
    };
  }
  static Map<String,String> map = new FlyweightMap();
  public static Map<String,String> capitals() {
    return map; // The entire map
  }
  public static Map<String,String> capitals(int size) {
    return select(size); // A partial map
  }
  static List<String> names =
    new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
  // All the names:
  public static List<String> names() { return names; }
  // A partial list:
  public static List<String> names(int size) {
    return new ArrayList<String>(select(size).keySet());
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    print(capitals(10));
    print(names(10));
    print(new HashMap<String,String>(capitals(3)));
    print(new LinkedHashMap<String,String>(capitals(3)));
    print(new TreeMap<String,String>(capitals(3)));
    print(new Hashtable<String,String>(capitals(3)));
    print(new HashSet<String>(names(6)));
    print(new LinkedHashSet<String>(names(6)));
    print(new TreeSet<String>(names(6)));
    print(new ArrayList<String>(names(6)));
    print(new LinkedList<String>(names(6)));
    print(capitals().get("BRAZIL"));
  }
} /* Output:
{ALGERIA=Algiers, ANGOLA=Luanda, BENIN=Porto-Novo, BOTSWANA=Gaberone, BULGARIA=Sofia, BURKINA FASO=Ouagadougou, BURUNDI=Bujumbura, CAMEROON=Yaounde, CAPE VERDE=Praia, CENTRAL AFRICAN REPUBLIC=Bangui}
[ALGERIA, ANGOLA, BENIN, BOTSWANA, BULGARIA, BURKINA FASO, BURUNDI, CAMEROON, CAPE VERDE, CENTRAL AFRICAN REPUBLIC]
{BENIN=Porto-Novo, ANGOLA=Luanda, ALGERIA=Algiers}
{ALGERIA=Algiers, ANGOLA=Luanda, BENIN=Porto-Novo}
{ALGERIA=Algiers, ANGOLA=Luanda, BENIN=Porto-Novo}
{ALGERIA=Algiers, ANGOLA=Luanda, BENIN=Porto-Novo}
[BULGARIA, BURKINA FASO, BOTSWANA, BENIN, ANGOLA, ALGERIA]
[ALGERIA, ANGOLA, BENIN, BOTSWANA, BULGARIA, BURKINA FASO]
[ALGERIA, ANGOLA, BENIN, BOTSWANA, BULGARIA, BURKINA FASO]
[ALGERIA, ANGOLA, BENIN, BOTSWANA, BULGARIA, BURKINA FASO]
[ALGERIA, ANGOLA, BENIN, BOTSWANA, BULGARIA, BURKINA FASO]
Brasilia
*///:~
```

Comment: This was not a question seeking debugging help at all, but a request for identification of an unfamiliar construct.

Comment: Rather than this program, it would be easy if you look at CountingMapData program initially(Its three or fours pages after this program). The use of AbstractSet makes this program complicated to a novice. Instead of AbstractSet , it can use a LinkedHashSet or any other Set. Look with that point, then it would be easy to understand....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's returning an [anonymous instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) of `FlyweightMap` which overrides [`entrySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#entrySet--)